# How to save items in a listview to an access database?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, ms-access, windows-forms-designer

How to save listview items in an access database? I've done research but i couldn't find the right answer. Can anyone help me?

my listview has column which are : ItemID, ItemName, Price, Quantity, TotalPrice and my access database has the same number and name of columns. I want to save all the data in my listview into an access database.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/095f7bcc-fe47-441d-947c-a814a449a55d/

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.csharpfriends.com/Forums/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=79222 :

to read to listview you should do the following:

```
void LoadListView() 
{ 
    DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con = 
        new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=C:\accessItems.mdb;");
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adpt = 
        new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Items", con); 
    adpt.Fill(ds); 
    DataTable table = ds.Tables[0]; 
    this.listView1.Items.Clear(); 
    foreach(DataRow r in table.Rows) 
        this.listView1.Items.Add(
            new ListViewItem(r["Value"].ToString()));//value is the field of name value 
}
```

to write a new item in the list view do this:

```
void SaveItem(ListViewItem item) 
{ 
    DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con = 
        new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=C:\accessItems.mdb;"); 
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = 
        new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("insert into Items(Value) values(" + item.Text + ")", con); 
    con.Open(); 
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    con.Close(); 
}
```